# how can I make ggplot2 X11 output less ugly?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone tell me how to make graphics plotted interactively to an X11 device look as good as it does when saved to a file? For example, I scatter plot part of the `diamonds` data set that comes with ggplot2 with:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, color=color, xlim=c(2,3), ylim=c(5000,10000))
ggsave("plot.png")
```

This is a screen shot of `qplot()`-ing directly to an X11 device. If you zoom on the dots you'll see they are all different-shaped splotches:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/a7fIZTE.png]

and this is the same thing `ggsave()`d to a png.  The dots look like, well, dots: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/A7TSyME.png]

I am on Ubuntu linux 14.04 with R 3.0.2, ggplot2 0.9.3.1-1, both installed via apt-get. I have cairodevice installed as well, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Take a look at `help(x11)`. It covers antialiasing and provides an example for how to set a hook in your `.Rprofile` to have any options you configure load on startup.

Comment: I tried `x11(type="cairo", antialias="subpixel")` with no luck...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed have cairo libraries and the `Cairo` package installed the `CairoX11` function should provide you the increased resolution.

```
require(Cairo)
CairoX11()
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, color=color, xlim=c(2,3), ylim=c(5000,10000))
```